# How to Get Background Image of Parent and Nested Divs to Scale Responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

How do I enable the background images of both my parent divs and nested divs to scale responsively in a mobile-first manner using the following media query.

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work! I want the entire page to scale responsively, which includes both images(especially the motorcycle helmet picture), as the screen size shrinks or enlarges.

I want to find out how do I set up my mobile-first `min-width media-query` to achieve the desired effect of the all the images, or only the motorcycle helmet image to scale from small to large from mobile to desktop. I also want the buttons to remain in the same exact positions as that happens. Thankyou so much for your help?

You can view my CodePen code here:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/KZqNdr/

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/9pnce8yr3/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1b.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;  
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.Motorcycle {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn.btn-default {
  color: #0040ff;
  font-size: .80em;
  font-family: Orbitron, sans-serif;
  line-height: 4em;  
}

.gstuff {
  background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/b9aat9l7j/G_Motorcycle_Helmet_2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 681px;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

#push-one {
  transform: translateY(200px);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-right: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

#push-two {
  transform: translateY(530px);
  background-color: #c6c6c4;
  border-bottom: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-right: 2px inset #FFF;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 500px){
  .gstuff {}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Motorcycle">
    <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
    <div class="gstuff">
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="push-one">
        Generate Quote
      </div>
      <div class="quote-box">
        <p id="quote"></p>
        <p id="author"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn btn-whatever" id="push-two">
        Tweet
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and deffective way is to use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`.

`cover` will always scale the background-image to fill the element completely, `contain` will always scale the image to be fully visible, both with keeping the width/height proportion intact to avoid distorted images.

Comment: I tried that as well, the page shrinks responsively, but the motorcycle helmet picture doesn't scale. I want the motorcyle helmet picture to scale smaller as the screen size decreases. I want to be able to see the entirety of the motorcycle helmet picture, not a portion of it. That's the goal I'm trying to achieve. Thanks sooo much!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but it seems you should restrict the element's width and height to the screen size (i.e. `width: 100vw`, `height: 100vh`, and the settings you used as `width` and `height` as `max-width` and `max-height`), and use `background-size: contain`.

Comment: Right now I have a mobile first `media-query` like this: `@media(min-width: 500px){ .gstuff{ max-width: 300px; max-height: 409px; } } and in the rest of my CSS, I have a set up like this: (Nested Div)  `.gstuff{ background-position: center; background-size: contain; width: 500px; height: 681px; margin: auto; opacity: 0.85; ` and like this (Main Div) `.container{ text-align: center; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;` But the motorcycle image scales large under `500px` and scales small over `500px` which is the opposite of what the `min-width` is supposed to achieve..